# CASE statement in where block with oracle procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I am trying to write a procedure where I am using CASE in where clause. not sure whats wrong here but below piece of code is not working.

it just says Errors: check compiler log .. I cant even check the error message. could you please help whats wrong here.

```
create or replace 
PACKAGE BODY PACKAGE1_PKG AS
PROCEDURE get_row(
    p_project           IN OUT VARCHAR2,
    p_version           IN OUT VARCHAR2,
    p_logical_name      IN OUT VARCHAR2,
    p_operation_name    IN OUT VARCHAR2,
    p_obsolete_flg      IN OUT CHAR,
    p_default_operation IN OUT CHAR,
    p_crt_dt            IN OUT DATE,
    p_crt_userid        IN OUT VARCHAR2) IS

BEGIN
errbuf  := NULL;
retcode := '0';

BEGIN <<lookup_row>>
  SELECT 
     project
    ,version
    ,logical_name
    ,operation_name
    ,obsolete_flg
    ,default_operation
    ,crt_dt
    ,crt_userid
  INTO 
     p_project
    ,p_version
    ,p_logical_name
    ,p_operation_name
    ,p_obsolete_flg
    ,p_default_operation
    ,p_crt_dt
    ,p_crt_userid
  FROM  TABLEA
  WHERE

    CASE 
            WHEN p_operation_name != 0 
            THEN operation_name = 'Y'
         ELSE 
            operation_name = p_operation_name
     END
  AND project = p_project
  AND   version = p_version
  AND   logical_name = p_logical_name;




END PACKAGE1_PKG;
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with the `case` statement? Are you sure that should be in the `where` clause and not in the `select` clause?

Comment: responded below on requirement.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use `CASE` like this. The way you use it is something like this:

```
CASE 
WHEN expression 1 THEN column/value 1
....
ELSE column/value default
END
```

In your case, you can change the code to something like

```
AND 
(
 (p_c != 0 AND d = 'Y')
 OR 
 (c = 0) --p_c = 0 and c=p_c is the same as c = 0
)
```

Comment: Hello, actually my requirement is different. in my procedure I will pass a variable... in case if I pass that(p_c) then assign that value to d  which should be part of where clause.  if I dont pass then in where clause I am adding another column and searching based on c ='Y'

Comment: I don't understand. Are you saying `p_a_ etc. are variables? Please edit your question and post the **ACTUAL** query that you will have.

Comment: p_operation_name is a variable which will be passed to this procedure... if its pass then assign this value to variable operation_name else assign operation_name variable to  = 'Y'

Comment: Hmm, my code still seems to be valid, because if your check for x != 0 is false, then x = 0 must be true. Unless, of course, x is NULL. What should be done if the parameter is null?

Comment: shree.pat18 - unfortunately thats not working... this does not justify the conditional block.

Comment: could you please check on CASE block above and help me resolving this issue.

Comment: Can you please **edit your question** and add exactly what you expect as output and what is going wrong? I am not able to understand what you mean by "does not justify the conditional block". Please update **your question** with this so that others can get a better idea and try to help.

Comment: Thanks shree.pat18 - it worked now. AND (p_operation_name IS NULL AND default_operation = 'Y')
      OR (operation_name = p_operation_name) ;